# Can i Attack an adjacent territory with troops from different territory

Tags: risk

I must attack an adjacent territory.

Do I have to attack with troops from an adjacent territory, or can I use troops from a non adjacent territory?

Comment: As a new user I'd appreciate reasoning behind the downvote? I was playing risk with my kids and my 11 yr old had interpreted the rules this way. Let me know what I did wrong so I don't do it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You attack from one territory into another. You may only use the troops in the territory you are attacking from in that attack.

Answer (score 1):

[Andrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/57028/25333) is correct - you attack from one territory into another. From [the official rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf):

> You must always have at least two armies in **the territory** you're
> attacking from.

and

> TO Attack. First announce both the territory you're attacking and **the
> one you're attacking from**. Then roll the dice against the opponent who
> occupies the opposing territory.

(emphasis mine)